# How to check for a flag within a case with getopts?

Tags: bash, shell

So I have a case statement that accepts three flags -w, -n, and s. I want to be able to manipulate stuff from -w and -n within the -s flag. How do I check for those flags within the s case?

```
    while getopts "sn:w:" option
    do
    case $option in
            n)
                    echo "The value of -n is $OPTARG"
                    #doing magic
                    echo $n_passwd
                    ;;
            w)
                    echo "The value of -w is $OPTARG"
                    for num in `seq 1 $OPTARG`
                    do
                            w_passwd=$(shuf -n"$OPTARG" "$RANDOM_WORDS" | tr -d '[:space:]')
                            echo $w_passwd
                    done
                    ;;
            s)
                    echo "You clicked -s"
                    #I want to manipulate variables from -n and -w flags here
                    if [ -w ]
                    tr 'aeiou' '4321' <<< $w_passwd
                    echo $w_passwd
                    ;;
            *)
                    echo "default value" ;;
    esac
```

Comment: In general, the only thing you do in the option-parsing loop is set variables that indicate what options were passed and/or their arguments. Then after the loop, you test for and use those values.

Comment: Requiring certain options to appear before other options is bad program design. POSIX explicitly states that option sequence should have no effect (for most utilities, except historical accidents). Alternative: provide more options, where each option does one thing well.